# NGINX disable auth for specific location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to disable basic auth for `app/folder#/dashboard/UUID?test=true` where UUID is an actual UUID.

I've tried with:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www...;
        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
        location ~ ^/app/folder#/dashboard/[0-9a-z-]+\?test=true {
                auth_basic          "off";
        }
}
```

I've tried both `"off"` and `off`. I even tried to just disable it for /app/folder#/ with `location /app/folder#`, but it didn't work. The only one it worked for was `/app/`.

Thank you

Comment: Does it work for: `location /app/folder`? Anything from the `#` onwards is [the fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax), and is not sent to the server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No, it didn't. I've already tried like that. The path is an url from kibana to load a dashboard. It looks like this `http://url/app/kibana#/dashboard/UUID?embed=true&_g=(refreshInterval%3A(pause%3A!f%2Cvalue%3A30000)%2Ctime%3A(from%3Anow-7d%2Cmode%3Aquick%2Cto%3Anow))`. I assume that everything after the `#` is sent to the kibana server, because it loads different dashboards based on the UUID, right? Maybe i can try with a regex something like /app/folder*, because if i just use `/app/` it only works for `URL/app`, but not for `URL/app/....`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, i understand what you mean for the #. So i can only try to filter until the #. Bummer :)